# Highlight searched table data and column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one table with some data. After some event I want to highlight column.

http://jsfiddle.net/bpGaf/

```
jQuery('#tableFilter td:eq(2)').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).css('background-color','#cc0');});
```

But It highlight only one cell even I have used **each** function.

Comment: it is bcoz u used :eq(2).if this is used,it will highlight only that particular cell

Comment: Also, consider using a CSS class instead. It will be much easier to change the specific color and style applied to the selected cells later from the stylesheet than hunting down the location in the javascript to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector says "Of all the `<td>` elements inside `#tableFilter`, consider only the 3rd one", rather than "Take the 3rd `<td>` in each `<tr>` inside that table" as it should.

This would do what you want it to do:

```
jQuery('#tableFilter tr').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color', '#cc0');
});​
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wtdk/)

Answer (score 2):

try this, its the smaller solution:

```
jQuery('#tableFilter tr').find('td:eq(2)').css('background-color','#cc0');
```

Comment: Lol, almost identical code to mine, seconds before I posted it, but you didn't explain why his code didn't work. But I'm glad we both agree on the correct approach.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of that way of one-lining it. Though, AFAIK, jQuery just does a `.each()` loop behind the scenes with your code as well, it's just not cluttering up your code. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The shortest code to highlight 3rd column:

> $('#tableFilter td:nth-child(3)').css('background','#cc0');

Comment: Nice and succinct, and a great use of the `:nth-child()` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Check the update in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bpGaf/2/